# ASP.NET Web Page with AtomFeed RSS feeds loading time too long

Tags: c#, async-await, rss

Now I have code which is sync, I need to make it async.
I tried what Visual Studio 2012 offers, the code have no mistackes but with no result.

Please help.

Code:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
        this.PopulateAtomFeed1();
        this.PopulateAtomFeed2();
        this.PopulateAtomFeed3();
        this.PopulateAtomFeed4();
    }



private void PopulateAtomFeed1()
{
    string RssFeedUrl = "http://www.faktor.mk/feed/ekonomija/";
    List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
    try
    {
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
        var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item").Take(10)
                     select new
                     {
                         title = x.Element("title").Value,
                         link = x.Element("link").Value,
                         pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                         description = x.Element("description").Value
                     });
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                Feeds f = new Feeds
                {
                    Title = i.title,
                    Link = i.link,
                    PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                    Description = i.description
                };

                feeds.Add(f);
            }
        }

        gvRss1.DataSource = feeds;
        gvRss1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        feeds = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It takes more than 12 seconds to comlete, which is too much. That is why I need async.

Comment: Your code is dependent on the speed of the server at http://www.faktor.mk/feed/ekonomija/. Try downloading the document first and then processing it or proxying the feed. That way you can get around the latency of the network and speed of the server.